Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be normal random variables. What is the distribution of $\sum X_i^2 \mid \sum X_i$?
Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be i.i.d. $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ random variables. Suppose that I have observed the sum, $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, and I want to know the distribution of the sum of the squares, $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$.
The context for this problem is that I have been simulating large datasets and then computing the sum and sum of squares for them, but I only need to store $n$ and these two sufficient statistics. Therefore I can make this more efficient by sampling from the distribution of the sum and then sampling from the conditional distribution of the sum of squares given the sum. I think the following is correct, but I am unsure.
Let $$S_1 = X_1 + \cdots X_n \textrm{ and } \ S_2 = X_1^2 + \cdots + X_n^2$$
We know that $S_1 \sim N(n\mu, n\sigma^2)$.
We can decompose
$$S_2 = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - 2\bar{X}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i + n\bar{X}^2 + n\bar{X}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2 + n\bar{X}^2,$$
where $\bar{X} = S_1 / n$ is the sample mean.
The term $$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{X_i - \bar{X}}{\sigma}\right)^2$$ has a chi-squared distribution with (n-1) degrees of freedom, so if we multiply the chi-squared random variable by $\sigma^2$ we have $$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2 \sim \sigma^2 \chi^2_{n-1}$$
Since $n\bar{X}^2 = S_1^2 / n$, the conditional distribution is $$S_2 \mid S_1 \sim \sigma^2 \chi^2_{n-1} + S_1^2/n.$$

I am not sure about the notation at the end, but in effect you seem to be saying $\frac{S_2 - S_1^2/n}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ and is independent of $S_1$.  That looks reasonable.
